# Typescript generate getters and setters

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to augment a class (properly typed) with getters and setters?

I have class like this:

```js
class Foo {
    private bar: string = '';
}
```

And I would like to write a function `augmentWithGettersAndSetters()`, that adds setters and getters for this class, basically turning it into this class:

```js
class Foo {
    private bar: string = '';

    public setBar(bar: string): this {
        this.bar = bar;

        return this;
    }

    public getBar(): string {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

Note: It is not sufficient to use VSCode's getter and setter refactor. I want to use chaining with the setters.

Comment: Have you looked into [class decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators)?

Comment: I have, but these can not change the type of the class, so the setters and getters would not be known to typescript. Or has that been changed and they can augment the type of the object they are attached to?

Comment: Getting a solution like this to play well with TS is not worth the trouble IMO. You can get something that works for the users of the class, for the inside of the class I don't think you can do it easily.

Comment: I doubt this would ever work with `private` properties, since those are explicitly forbidden from being accessed externally, including whatever the implementation of `augmentWithGettersAndSetters()` would be.  And I also doubt you could get the setter to return the right `this` type.  And you would probably need to specify the property names when calling `augment...` also.

Comment: Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8EnVN) is the closest I could get.  If that fully addresses the question I could write up how it works; otherwise what am I missing?